# Does scala collection's flatten keep order?

Tags: scala

I have looked at the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.html) of flatten and the example seems to indicate the order of the elements in the result maintains the order of the input. Is there a documentation or source code we can reference to make sure that it is the case? Or, is the documentation "Converts this collection of traversable collections into a collection formed by the elements of these traversable collections" enough to confirm this?

**Update**: My original question was not clear enough. I wanted to ask about the collections that maintain order internally (like List) and we use the default implicit traversable in flatten(). prayagupd has answered this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you read the [`flatten` function](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.scala#L169) of `scala 2.12.x`, you can see it sequentially adding given inputs to a new collection.**

```
  //a sequential view of the collection
  private def sequential: TraversableOnce[A] = this.asInstanceOf[GenTraversableOnce[A]].seq

  def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => /*<:<!!!*/ GenTraversableOnce[B]): CC[B] = {
    val b = genericBuilder[B]
    for (xs <- sequential)
      b ++= asTraversable(xs).seq
    b.result()
  }
```

you can verify with example as well,

```
scala> List(List("order1", "order2"), List("order10", "order11")).flatten
res1: List[String] = List(order1, order2, order10, order11)
```

**The order remains same even if you provide your own traversable,**

```
scala> val asTraversable: List[String] => List[String] = list => list.map(elem => s"mutated $elem")
asTraversable: List[String] => List[String] = $$Lambda$1271/1988351538@513bec8c

scala> List(List("order1", "order2"), List("order10", "order11")).flatten(asTraversable)
res2: List[String] = List(mutated order1, mutated order2, mutated order10, mutated order11)
```

**NOTE: above only applies to underlying data-structure that maintain the order.**
For example `Set` does not maintain order

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).seq
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)
```

Comment: There is a major exception: `Set` is `Traversable`, and won't preserve order (once you get past 4 elements).